# RAISERROR forces msg_id > 50000 in SQL2014, but legacy code has msg_ids lower than 50000

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr, raiserror

Where I work, we will replace SQL 2005 and 2008 with SQL 2014.

We are finding a big problem.  The `RAISERROR` function, doesnt accept `cod error < 50000`.

Many of our applications use cod erro in this condition, with same code, but different msg.

I think in order to solve it I'll need to override RAISERROR with CLR (C# assembly).  Is this possible?

Another problem, we need make this update in sql 2005 and 2008 before this change to the new servers. I know has now throw, but don´t work in sql 2008.

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 Divide by zero error
>   encountered."
>
> Cod. Erro = "Msg 50000

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. What is the issue here? 50000 has been the recommended base for a user defined error since 2005. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: @NathanKoop where did that error message come from?

Comment: I know, but it's a legacies

Comment: @AndréPedro saying its legacy code doesn't mean you should expect to never have to bring it up to date.  You've had 10 years where this was coming.

Comment: @paqogomez it was added by the OP, but I accidentely overwrote it in on my first edit.

Comment: @Andy, I can´t change now all applications, I need try override RAISERROR or another solution a low impact.

Comment: You can't; so either change your apps or move back to a previous version of SQL server.